# making switch "if" statements

Tags: ios, xcode, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm making a Pay Calculator for my companies employees. It takes Federal Tax, Social Security Tax, and Medicare Tax into consideration.  However, some of the employees are independent contractors and do not pay certain taxes.  Thus all of these taxes are on their separate switch button.  I'm having trouble making the "if" statements for these switches, because I have never done a switch before.  I'm hoping someone could lead me in the right direction!

Code:

```
- (IBAction)calculateButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    float dailyRate = [self.dailyRateTextField.text floatValue];
    float daysWorked = [self.daysWorkedTextField.text floatValue];
    float grossPay = dailyRate * daysWorked;
    float taxRate = .72;
    float ssRate = .938;
    float medRate = .9855;
    float netPay = grossPay * taxRate * medRate * ssRate;
    self.dailyRateTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.2f", dailyRate];
    self.netIncomeTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.2f", netPay];
    self.grossIncomeTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.2f", grossPay];

    if (fedTaxSwitchOutlet.on) {}

    if (!fedTaxSwitchOutlet.on) {}

    if (ssTaxSwitchOutlet.on){}

    if (!ssTaxSwitchOutlet.on) {}

    if (medTaxSwitchOutlet.on) {}

    if (!medTaxSwitchOutlet.on) {}

    }    

}
```

Does anyone know how I would do an equation in the "if" statement?  Like if the Medicare Tax Switch is turned off I still would like the app to calculate the persons the social security tax and the federal tax.

Comment: For your scenario use `if()....else...`.

Comment: what about the equations?  How would I do an equation with floats in an "if" statement?

Comment: Are you familiar with the basics of the C or Objective-C language?  The use of a `UISwitch` control has no real bearing on how to write your calculation code.  The `on` property of a `UISwitch` is a boolean which you are checking in the `if` statement.  Put the relevant "equations" inside the `{}` that correspond to that condition.  Don't confuse the C `switch` statement with the `UISwitch` control.

Comment: @anna OP is asking for switch...case... Control structure not uiswitch. :)

Comment: Fixed.  Yogesh was right.  I switched out the ! statements and replaced with else statements right below and then used my float identifiers to do the equation.  All set now.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Yogesh Suthar was right, heres what I did:

```
if (medTaxSwitchOutlet.on) netPay = netPay;
else netPay = netPay + medgrossrate;
if (ssTaxSwitchOutlet.on) netPay = netPay;
else netPay = netPay + ssgrossrate;
if (fedTaxSwitchOutlet.on) netPay = netPay;
else netPay = netPay + minusTaxes;
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your variables above your if statement. This allows you to read them within the if statements, this is called `scope`. If you're going to continue working on this project, please read up about the basics of variable scope.

Also if you don't need to do anything if the `UISwitch` is off, then don't look for it - all you need to do is see if the switch is on. If it is, then calculate.

```
float federal = 0.0;
float socialSecurity = 0.0;
float medicare = 0.0;

if (fedTaxSwitchOutlet.on) {
  federal = [self calculateFederal]
}

if (ssTaxSwitchOutlet.on){
  socialSecurity = [self calculateSocialSecurity]
}

if (medTaxSwitchOutlet.on) {
  medicare = [self calculateMedicare];
}

float total = federal + socialSecurity + medicare;
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm taking a course in Objective C right now, but some of the things I don't quite understand yet.  I'm serving in Afghanistan, and I'm trying to do this in my spare time to give me something to look forward to when I do get out of here.  Thank you for your help, I really do appreciate it!  :)